# Use new keyword if hiding was intended

Tags: c#, inheritance, warnings, new-operator

I have the following snippet of code that's generating the "Use new keyword if hiding was intended" warning in VS2008:

```
public double Foo(double param)
{
   return base.Foo(param);
}
```

The `Foo()` function in the base class is protected and I want to expose it to a unit test by putting it in wrapper class solely for the purpose of unit testing. I.e. the wrapper class will not be used for anything else. So one question I have is: **is this accepted practice?**

Back to the `new` warning. **Why would I have to new the overriding function in this scenario?**

Comment: does your base class have a constructor?

Comment: @Tom: This has nothing to do with the constructor.

Comment: see also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261177/using-friend-declarations-for-unit-testing-bad-idea for a discussion of a similar practice

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The `new` just makes it absolutely clear that you know you are stomping over an existing method. Since the existing code was `protected`, it isn't as big a deal - you can safely add the `new` to stop it moaning.

The difference comes when your method does something different; any variable that references the *derived* class and calls `Foo()` would do something different (even with the same object) as one that references the *base* class and calls `Foo()`:

```
SomeDerived obj = new SomeDerived();
obj.Foo(); // runs the new code
SomeBase objBase = obj; // still the same object
objBase.Foo(); // runs the old code
```

This could obviously have an impact on any existing code that knows about `SomeDerived` and calls `Foo()` - i.e. it is now running a completely different method.

Also, note that you could mark it `protected internal`, and use `[InternalsVisibleTo]` to provide access to your unit test (this is the most common use of `[InternalsVisibleTo]`; then your unit-tests can access it directly without the derived class.

Answer (score 40):

The key is that you're *not* overriding the method. You're hiding it. If you were overriding it, you'd need the `override` keyword (at which point, unless it's virtual, the compiler would complain because you *can't* override a non-virtual method).

You use the `new` keyword to tell both the compiler and anyone reading the code, "It's okay, I know this is only hiding the base method and not overriding it - that's what I meant to do."

Frankly I think it's rarely a good idea to hide methods - I'd use a different method name, like Craig suggested - but that's a different discussion.

Comment: One place that I find hiding useful is when I have an interface whose implementation uses a base class that I don't want to change, only to use the methods of. This way, I can use the base class methods in objects that use instances of the interface, not the class that implements the interface, e.g. `Ctor(IFoo foo){int x = foo.OriginalBaseMethod();}` instead of  `Ctor(Foo foo){int x = foo.OriginalBaseMethod();}`

Answer (score 8):

You're changing the visibility without the name. Call your function TestFoo and it will work. Yes, IMHO it's acceptable to subclass for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

You'll always find some tricky situations where the `new` keyword can be used for hiding while it can be avoided most of the times.

However, recently I really needed this keyword, mainly because the language lacks some other proper synthax features to complete an existing accessor for instance:

If you consider an old-fashioned class like:

```
KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>
```

You will notice that the accesor for acessing the items trough index is:

```
TItem this[Int32 index] { get; set; }
```

Has both `{ get; set; }` and they are of course mandatory due to the inheritance regarding `ICollection<T>` and `Collection<T>`, but there is only one `{ get; }` for acessing the items through their keys (I have some guesses about this design and there is plenty of reasons for that, so please note that I picked up the `KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>)` just for illustrations purposes).

Anyway so there is only one getter for the keys access:

```
TItem this[TKey key] { get; }
```

But what about if I want to add the `{ set; }` support, technically speaking it's not that stupid especially if you keep reasoning from the former definition of the propery, it's just a method... the only way is to implement explicitly another dummy interface but when you want to make implicit you have to come up with the `new` keyword, I'm hiding the accessor definition, keeping the get; base definition and just add a set stuffed with some personal things to make it work.

I think for this very specific scenario, this keyword is perfecly applicable, in particular in regards to a context where there is no brought to the `{ get; }` part.

```
  public new TItem this[TKey key]
  { 
      get { return base... }
      set { ... }
  }
```

That's pretty much the only trick to avoid this sort of warning cause the compiler is suggesting you that you're maybe hiding without realizing what you are doing.