# new Keyword confusion

Tags: c#, .net

All -

Have read various articles on the new keyword and when it should be used:

MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fawty39(v=vs.80).aspx

StackOverflow - [benefit of using new keyword in derived class member having same name with base class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229171/benefit-of-using-new-keyword-in-derived-class-member-having-same-name-with-base)

Here is a sample code I have written to practice this concept

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal a2 = new Dog();
        a2.Talk();
        a2.Sing();
        a2.Greet();
        a2.Dance();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

class Animal
{
    public Animal()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Animal constructor");
    }

    public void Talk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Animal is Talking");
    }

    public virtual void Sing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Animal is Singing");
    }

    public void Greet()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Animal is Greeting");
    }

    public virtual void Dance()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Animal is Dancing");
    }
}

//Derived Class Dog from Animal
class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dog Constructor");
    }

    public new void Talk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dog is Talking");
    }

    public override void Sing()
    {
        //base.Sing();
        Console.WriteLine("Dog is Singing");
    }

    public new void Dance()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dog is Dancing");
    }
}
```

Any my output is coming as follows:

[image]

Whats confusing me is that by using the new keyword in the derieved class is actually showing an output of the base class. Isnt that wrong - isnt new keyword supposed to hide the base class membership so the result for Animal is Talking and Animal is Dancing should not be printed.

Thanks

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014295/new-keyword-in-method-signature

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "new" means the method is "new" and not an "override".  Therefore, if you call a method by that name from the base, it hasn't been overriden so the derived won't be called.

Answer (score 0):

This was confusing to me as well but to put it simply:

The new keyword hides the child's member from the parent.