# C# virtual methods override the return type & method arguments

Tags: c#, polymorphism, virtual, overriding

I want to init virtual method with exact name in abstract class.

And in class, which is the inheritor override method such, that I can override:

- the return type of the base method
- arguments of the method

To show you, what I'm really want to do is smth like this:

```
abstract class A
{
    public virtual void Func1() { }
}

class B : A
{
    override string Func1(int a, int b)
    {
         return (a + b).ToString();
    }
}
```

I know, that C# requires to use the return type/args as in base class, but maybe there are some hints with keyword `new` in this situation?

Comment: Yes, there is a keyword `new`, but it is not overriding, it is just hides a member.

Comment: B.Func1 is not an override but and overload.  So you're not overriding

Comment: You cannot use the new, static, or virtual modifiers to modify an override method.

Comment: What's the point of inheriting then?

Comment: @Forty-Two polymorphic point

Comment: @OlegOrlov If the signature is different, then the method *cannot* be polymorphic.  The whole point of polymorphism is that you don't know, or care, what the derived type is, because all of the types implement a common interface.  If each derived type has a different interface, then the caller *must* know what the derived type is, and cannot act as if any type is just an instance of the base type.

Comment: @Servy the point is that you give me polymorphic point in informatics (in the chemistry polymorphism is more greater stuff), besides you give me the polymorphism which is mure suitable for C#, but not for the base theory of it. There is such stuff as: "polymorphism of the second order... N-oreder", which can't be designed in C#, but can be in Lisp/Haskell (even in F#) (where there callers must now the exact types). Despite the fact that polymorphisms in computer science came later than in other sciences.

Comment: You probably should show an example of how you want resulting code that uses this function to look like and inline above comment (or maybe ask completely new question "how to implement/mimic following behavior of F# in C#"). I think what you shown currently does not show what you want to achieve and looks completely against C# specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only `override` the exact name and arguments. You can `new` whatever you want, but that's not overriding--just hiding in the case of an exact match.

I think in your situation you will either want to create overloads for all possible combinations, or create a single base, abstract method which takes a single type that can contain the arguments you want.

Example:

```
public abstract void Func1( MyArgumentsType input );
```

Now derived classes are compelled to override a method but you can pass a robust set of arguments to the method that can handle more scenarios.

Polymorphism works to your advantage here, as you can then pass derived argument types to the method with situation-specific properties. Of course, this requires the implementing method to understand the more derived argument type.

Answer (score 3):

Your cant'd do this. Overriding a method requires to have the exact same signature, which includes parameters and return type. There is no way for you to tell a compiler to override a method with different parameters and return type.

If you want polymorphic behavior, you need to have compatible signatures. Otherwise compiler can't guarantee, that the required method will be found polymorphically.

There is no concivable way to treat signatures `void Func1()` and `string Func1(int a, int b)` as polymorphic. You can generalize them with `out` parameters of pass lambdas inside, but anyway - to take advantage of polymorphic behavior  you need to bring them to one common signature.

Answer (score 3):

Method overriding means modifying the virtual *implementation* of an inherited member and not it's *signature*. As you pointed out the `new` keyword will hide the base class's implementation of the member with the same name. However it is only optional, take a look at this 
 [benefit of using new keyword in derived class member having same name with base class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229171/benefit-of-using-new-keyword-in-derived-class-member-having-same-name-with-base)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to achieve behavior similar to `ToString` method that have many different flavors for different types (like `.ToString()` and `float.ToString("c")`).

In this case different implementations of `ToString` are not implementations of `Object.ToString` but rather normal additional method on derived objects that resolved appropriately based on arguments. All derived classes endup with one virtual `ToString` method (coming from base class and potentially implemented in current class) and optionally other similarly named methods that are not virtual.

Note that in C# result type newer taken into account in function resolution time, so you can't really have 2 functions with the same name and same arguments and expect one to be "correctly" picked. If both are visible at the same time you'll get compile time error. `new` keyword in front of method makes only that method visible for that class (and derived ones) and hiding base class method with the same signature. Unfortunately doing so pretty much guarantees a lot of confusion when one uses variable of base class holding derived class to call this method - the virtual one from base class will be called despite all efforts to hid one.

Comment: +1 for "confusion"...I've found that `new` is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it...how will it work? Say you have an reference whose static type is `A` but dynamic type is `B`, as follows:

```
foo(B b) { bar(b); }
bar(A a) { 
}
```

The idea behind overriding is that you call a method on super/base and it resolves to the overridden implementation. By that logic you should be able to, in `bar`, call `a.Func1()` and it should call the method in `B`:

```
a.Func1(???)
```

**But that is not possible here, because of missing parameters.**

There are notions of parameter contravariance and return type covariance; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/837178/18573) is an interesting answer in SO, with a link to a post by Eric Lippert that should be an interesting read.

Comment: maybe by the same mechanism as in: F#, Lisp, Haskell. Because there they realized, but there is some dynamic types. True C # with each version of himself becoming more and more dynamic-typed. Look at my answer to Servy's comment in the beginning of this Q.

Comment: Are you saying overriding with completely different signature works in these other languages?

Comment: Yes, I have told exactly this. Those dynamic languages use a different mechanism in work with the signature of methods.

Comment: How would you expect this work in `C#`? For example, what would you think you can replace `???` with in my example and have the call dispatched to `B.Func1`? If the dynamic type of `a` does not accept those parameters, would that be a run-time error?

Comment: yes! you are right. you may catch runtime errors using such technique with those languages, but also you may not to catch. It depends only on you.

Comment: So I guess that is a constraint of a statically typed language, with its own set of benefit, namely the type safety that the above call can never fail to resolve